# javascript/jquery url shortner/compressor

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, compression

I have to pass context variables,i.e. current state along with my URL. But this is making my URLs very long enought. I need to shorten my URLs such that I am able to decompress them and extract my context variables for the use of my application and also when a user shares the compressed URL with other user, he should be able to view the application in the exact state as the sender was viewing.

Most of the solutions I found over internet and stackoverflow.com are suggesting bit.ly but I can't use it as it is proprietary application.

Can you suggest javascript/jquery alternative to bit.ly which will shorten my URL on the fly?

Comment: http://dev.bitly.com/

Comment: As far as I could understand from this link that you gave is that it will shorten the entire URL.. I need to shorten only the part of the URL where context variables are there and not the entire URL as it is an proprietary application so the user wants to see the domain name as it is.

Comment: But you cant do that with JavaScript you need server side code and a db for that

Comment: so there is no way to do that client-side?

Comment: Store the state in a db table and pass around the a representative token

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Put whatever it is you want to include in the URL into a database table, for that row generate a shorter value; hash of the data, guid, random n character string etc. and return that as the data to pass around. When you receive that data in a request, reverse the process with a lookup.